# sequelize DB clears out after restarting node app

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i am new to node and in my app i am using sequelize for my DB. 
Whenever i restart my node app, the DB data get cleared out. 
Any idea how to fix this?

I am not sure what to do

Comment: What you should do is show us your code!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is very likely that you're calling `sequelize.sync({force:true})` after defining your model.  By passing `{force:true}`, Sequelize drops and recreates all your tables.